# What is the difference between overturned, reversed and remanded?

Tags: united-kingdom, court, appeal

I'm reading a document I don't fully understand.

In it, it states:

"It is not appropriate for the court of appeals to review this point, which is to be returned to the High Court"

It also states early on that the high courts decision has been 'overturned'

Based on the original statement, does that mean the case is closed, or remanded to the high court for reconsideration

What are the differences in the definitions?

Answer (score 1):

There is an important difference between "the decision" and "this point". Without a link nobody can be certain; but it is entirely possible for the appeal court to overturn (or reverse) the lower court's decision because it was made on the wrong basis, and then to remit the case back to that court to be considered again on the proper basis.